# Why does crontab execute one python file and not the other?

Tags: python, macos, cron

My crontab has two tasks, b.py and a.py

```
* * * * * cd Desktop/pp && /usr/bin/python b.py >> b.out
* * * * * cd Desktop/pp && /usr/bin/python a.py >> a.out
```

b.py is just

```
import os
import time

print("Running XD")
os.mkdir(str(int(time.time())))
```

and crontab runs it every minute, like it should. But crontab doesn't run a.py, which is

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import pyscreeze

APCS = "APCS link here"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(APCS)

print("running!!!!")
```

I have no idea why, they're exactly the same on the crontab and a.py works when I run it from the terminal. I'm using Mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: First thing you need to check if that both files had the right permissions. you can check the permission flags with `ls -l` on the directory they are located.

Comment: a.py has -rw-r--r--@ and b.py has -rw-r--r--. I'm not familiar with these, is that a problem?

Comment: On `a.py` you are using libs that operate over a GUI, that can be problematic. 
Are you at least getting some output on `a.out`? share that if possible

Comment: If not, append `2>&1` to the crontab entry so that stderr messages also get logged.

Comment: I wasn't getting any output to a.out but I deleted the import pyautogui and import pyscreeze and it works now (But I think I might want to use them later so...)

Comment: And when I bring import pyautogui back again, the error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named pyautogui